# Amazon EC2 Creating Tunnel with OpenVPN

Tags: amazon-ec2, vpn, openvpn, amazon-vpc

I have followed these instructions:
http://aws.amazon.com/articles/0639686206802544

I can ping the VPN endpoints and I have the corresponding VPC CIDR pointing to the EC2 instance in the route table.  Here is my config:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun

# Remote peer and network
remote Elastic_IP
route 10.0.0.0/16

# Configure local and remote VPN endpoints
ifconfig 169.254.255.1 169.254.255.2

# The pre-shared static key
secret /etc/openvpn/ovpn.key

keepalive 10 120
persist-key
persist-tun
log /var/log/openvpn.log
verb 3
```

When I look at my logs, I get this error:

```
RESOLVE: Cannot resolve host address: 10.0.0.0/16: Name or service not known
OpenVPN ROUTE: failed to parse/resolve route for host/network: 10.0.0.0/16
```

in VPC1, the CIDR is 172.31.0.0/16 which is targeting the EC2 instance also running OpenVPN.  I'm getting the same error from the Instance in VPC2 with the corresponding CIDR.  Just for testing, i stopped the IPTABLES service

I am running the Amazon linux AMI image (x64) as specified in the article I linked.

Comment: So where does ipsec come in? You mentioned it in your title...

Comment: Sorry - networking is not my strength.  I'm trying to connect two subnets together using OpenVPN and while the endpoints can ping each other, they cannot see the CIDR

Answer (score 0):

You can't use CIDR notation for the `route` configuration. Try instead:

```
route 10.0.0.0 255.255.0.0
```